# Testing a CKEditor in with Ruby and Capybara-webkit

Tags: javascript, ruby, testing, ckeditor, capybara

I am dealing with the following issue:
I try to insert text into a CKEditor and save it with the Submit button but as soon as I click the submit button the old text appears.
Im Doing this in a Ruby/Cucumber environment and my Webdriver is :Webkit

So this is the HTML before i changed anything:

```html
<h1 class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_focus" data-ng-model="module.newModule.data.headline" data-ckeditor="ckEditorOptions" data-char-limit="100" data-ng-focus="module.setCharacterLimitCounter(100, 'headline')" data-ng-if="module.inlineEditingEnabled || module.showEditText" tabindex="0" spellcheck="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" contenteditable="true">
Test 25.11.2016
<br/>
13:24
<br type="_moz"/>
</h1>
```

Now I tried to edit it with the following Rubycode:

```
find(:xpath, ".//*[@id='module']/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/h1[@title='Rich Text Editor, editor1']", :visible =>false).set("some Text")
```

And now the Html-code looks like this:

```html
<h1 class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr" data-ng-model="module.newModule.data.headline" data-ckeditor="ckEditorOptions" data-char-limit="100" data-ng-focus="module.setCharacterLimitCounter(100, 'headline')" data-ng-if="module.inlineEditingEnabled || module.showEditText" tabindex="0" spellcheck="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" contenteditable="true">Some Text</h1>
```

When I click the Submit button:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-medium" role="button" data-ng-click="module.forward()">
<span class="ng-hide" data-ng-show="module.item.newModuleInstanceOnEdit">Weiter</span>
<span data-ng-hide="module.item.newModuleInstanceOnEdit">Fertig</span>
</button>
```

with

```
find(:xpath, "Xpath_to_button").click
```

the Html looks like this:

```html
<h1 class="ng-binding ng-scope" data-ng-bind-html="module.item.data.headline" data-ng-if="!module.inlineEditingEnabled && !module.showEditText">
Test 25.11.2016
<br/>
13:24
</h1>
```

It might have something to do with this script on the Webpage:

```js
<script id="moduleNameDialog.html" type="text/ng-template">   <div class="default-dialog modal-dialog-module-naming"> <div class="modal-header"> <h3 class="modal-title">Vorlage speichern</h3> <a class="close-icon" href="" data-ng-click="dialog.cancel()" tabindex="-1">X</a> </div> <form name="dialog.moduleNamingForm" role="form" class="dtag-validation" novalidate="novalidate" data-ng-submit="dialog.moduleNamingForm.$valid &amp;&amp; dialog.module.checkModuleName(dialog.close)"> <div class="modal-body"> <p> Benennen Sie Ihre Version des Moduls – so können Sie diese als Vorlage später wiederverwenden. </p> <div class="text-small">Der Name muss 4-40 Zeichen lang sein. Erlaubte Zeichen: -!§$%&amp;/()=?+*~,#</div> <div class="floating-lbl-field-group center-block margin-top-10"> <label for="moduleName">Name</label> <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="moduleName" placeholder="Name" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-ZäöüÜÄÖß0-9-\s!§$%\x26/()=?+*~,#]{4,40}" data-ng-model="dialog.module.newModule.moduleInstanceName" data-validation-tooltip="Bitte geben Sie einen gültigen Namen ein" data-validation="" autofocus="autofocus" /> </div> </div> <div class="modal-footer"> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-medium btn-half-width" href="" data-ng-click="dialog.module.back(dialog.close)"> Zurück </a> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium btn-half-width" data-validation-submit=""> Fertig </button> </div> </form> </div> </script>
```

I tried a lot of stuff and I somehow cannot use page_execute because I always get the Error:

> Javascript failed to execute (Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError)

even with the most simple function webkit_debug gives:

> undefined|1|SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent. 
>   Finished "Reset()" with response "Success()" 
>   Wrote response true ""

I'm using:

- capybara-webkit version 1.11.1
- capybara version 2.4.4
- cucumber 2.4.0

Comment: The fact that you're using `visible: false` to find an element and then trying to set the value is a massive red flag that you're doing something wrong (using `visible: false` at all when testing is a smaller red flag).  If the element isn't visible on the page then a user couldn't interact with it which means you're probably setting the value to the wrong element.  You need to find the element that is visible on the screen that the user interacts with and call set or send_keys on that element.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole So I left the visible :false option out and capybara stills finds the right element (I actually needed it for an invisible overlay). It sadly does not make a difference. The set method seems to work since the heading is changed just when I press the button Submit it does not save my changes. I am pretty sure this has to do with the javascript of the CKEditor. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: You can try `find(...).send_keys("some text")` instead of `set` - it may be the editor is dependant on events not generated by `set`